# Div next to div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs and i want div2 will be next to div1. I tried use `float:left` and `display:inline` but nothing help.
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95rmz/1/)

How to do this?

P.S Sorry for stupid question but Im learning

Comment: Can you please write us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float: left` and `box-sizing: border-box`:

```
#div1 , #div2{
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95rmz/4/

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/95rmz/3/

```
<div class="row" style="width: 390px;">
  <div id="div1" style="width: 190px; border: solid black 1px; float: left; margin-right: 5px;">
      Street
      <input class="form-rej-normal" type="text">
      <div class="errorMessage" id="User_street_em_" style="">
          Pole Ulica nie może być puste.
      </div>    
   </div>
   <div id="div2" style="width: 190px; border: solid black 1px; float: left;">
       Numer domu       
           <input class="form-rej-normal" type="text">      
               <div class="errorMessage" id="User_house_number_em_" style="">
                    Pole Ulica nie może być puste.
               </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can then try to follow this approach

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="position:relative; width:auto; height:auto; float:left; border:solid red 1px;">
        this is div 1
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative; width:auto; height:auto; float:left; border:solid red 1px;">
        this is div 2
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For testing purpose you can also add `border:1px;` to check if your div tags are occupying more space than the resolution of your screen

Answer (score 0):

decrease the width of divs. if the first div is of full width then how can 2nd div come next to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not calculating the width correctly. You set a `380px` on the main div and give a `190px` to each contained div.

That would be fine if you did just that, but you also added a border around each div, so now each of them has an extra 2px (1px left and 1px right) so they are actually 192px each. so you can solve it in several ways:

1. Set the main div to at least 184px.
2. Set `box-sizing: border-box;`, that will cause the browser to put the borders inside the div and not add to it's width - see here for more data: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95rmz/6/